# pthread_mutex in android ndk

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to render a video on a surface,When i try to change render surface during rendering but application crashes due to `mNativeSurface = NULL` in render loop.What i am doing wrong

Decoder.h

```
class Decoder {
private:
    ANativeWindow* mNativeSurface;
    static void* threadStartCallback(void *myself);
    pthread_mutex_t _mutex_window;
public:
    void changeSurface(JEnv* env,jobject surface);


}
```

Decoder.cpp

```
class Decoder{
    public Decoder(JEnv* env,jobject surface){
        pthread_mutex_init(&_mutex_window, 0);
        mNativeSurface= ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env,surface);
       // create a thread and pass surface as widow
        pthread_create(&_threadId, 0, threadStartCallback, this);

    }

    void changeSurface(JEnv* env,jobject surface){
     //after some time i am changinf surface
       pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex_window);
       mNativeSurface= ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env,surface);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex_window);    

    }

    void* Decoder::threadStartCallback(void *myself)
    {
        while(/* condition */){
        //When i change surface while loop in sleep
         pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex_window);
            Rendering on mNativeSurface //rendering ----
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex_window);

           /*
            *Decoding + Rendering in while loop
            */      
        } 
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like `ANativeWindow_fromSurface` returned NULL then. Perhaps you called `changeSurface` before the Activity's `onStart` was called? Btw, you should probably release the previous native window before acquiring a new one.

Comment: I am releasing previous window